# MySQL Connector C++ Visual Studio CLR throw exception

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, clr, mysql-connector

I want to create Windows app, which uses DB through MySQL. I try work with DB in Console App, it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mysql_connection.h>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

const std::string server = "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306";
const std::string username = "root";
const std::string password = "root";

int main() {
    sql::Driver* driver = nullptr;
    sql::Connection* conn = nullptr;
    sql::Statement* stmt = nullptr;
    sql::PreparedStatement* pstmt = nullptr;
    sql::ResultSet* res = nullptr;
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    try {
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        conn = driver->connect(server, username, password);
        std::cout << "Connection Successful!";
        
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException& eSQL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed with exception: " << eSQL.what() << std::endl;
    }

    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete conn;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create UI Windows Form. I do same things, it has compile, but connection to DB failed (exc. "Unable to connect to localhost"). Server is running.

```
private: System::Void btnConnect_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        const std::string server = "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306";
        const std::string username = "root";
        const std::string password = "root";

            sql::Driver* driver = nullptr;
            sql::Connection* conn = nullptr;
            sql::Statement* stmt = nullptr;
            sql::PreparedStatement* pstmt = nullptr;
            sql::ResultSet* res = nullptr;
            try {
                driver = get_driver_instance();
                conn = driver->connect(server, username, password);
                label_connection->Text = "Successful connection!";
            
            }
            catch (sql::SQLException& eSQL) {
                label_connection->Text = gcnew String(eSQL.what());
            }

            delete res;
            delete stmt;
            delete conn;
        
    }
```

In Console App Project I add next options: Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependecies is *"mysqlcppconn-static.lib"* added and C/C++ -> Preprocessing -> Definitions is "STATIC_CONCPP" added.
With same options CLR Project fall down with many compile errors LNK2038 with link to *mysqlcppconn-static.lib*. I changed Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependecies to *"mysqlcppconn.lib"*,and it is compile, but connection unable. What am I doing wrong? How to use correct MySQL connector with c++ Windows Form CLR project in Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: Problem has been solved. Needed to link libraries for Debug build to libs from Debug directory and for release build to lib directory itself.